# Handling formik form when validation error occurs

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a formik form in react native code as follow.
Full runnable link can be view at:
[here](https://snack.expo.io/HJMkbEQy8)

**Current behaviour:** 
Validation can only be done with `handleSubmit`, with cannot be use for handle further action. Note than `onSubmit` will not be trigger if `handleSubmit` detects there is any validation error.

```
 <Button onPress={handleSubmit} style={styles.button}>
     Submit
 </Button>
```

**Expected solution:** 
A lifecycle event called when validation fails after an attempted submit (eg: `onValidationError`), where i can access all the input validation error props for further action.

Eg: I would like to handle something (like pop up an alert or scroll to first error message when validation fail)

The code is expected to be something like follow, or any other way of doing it can also be accepted. As long as i can handle event when validation error occurs.

```
 <Formik
    onSubmit={values => {
       alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
       Keyboard.dismiss();
    }}
    onValidationError={errorValues => {
       // any action here
       // note that onValidationError is not a built in function
       // but it would be best if it can be achieved this way
       // else any other equivalent solution also can be accepted
    }}
    validationSchema={validationSchema}>
```

**What have tried?**
I have tried to integrated 2 solution here. But failed to get it work.
https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik/issues/1019 
https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik/issues/1484

Comment: There is no such prop as `onValidationError`. I think you are trying to use your custom method as prop to `<Formik>` which does not identify it as a prop.

Comment: @MeetZaveri yes there is no such prop nor an equivalent built in solution for that. But how could i achieve same effect where i can perform action on validation error after handlesubmit is called.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use `isValid` prop(from `<Formik>`'s render props) on `<form>`'s `onsubmit` event by bypassing your logic there as ([Documentation](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/formik#isvalid-boolean))

```
<form
  onSubmit={e => {
    console.log("isValid", isValid);
    isValid
      ? handleSubmit(e)
      : alert("Handle your custom method instead here");
  }}
>
```

You can access `isValid` prop from render props on formik's

```
 {props => {
    const {
      values,
      touched,
      errors,
      dirty,
      isSubmitting,
      handleChange,
      handleBlur,
      handleSubmit,
      handleReset,
      isValid // add this to your code
    } = props;
    return ( ... your code );
}}
```

I have also made codesandbox, you can view working example here - https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-jennings-7wq0f

**Note** : This is not officially mentioned on any issues on formik repository or anywhere, but this is custom way intercept `submit` action on `<form>`'s `onsubmit` event

Hope this was helpful!

Answer (score 4):

Showing a notification on failed form submission can be achieved with a custom component using [useFormikContext](https://formik.org/docs/api/useFormikContext):

```
import { useFormikContext } from 'formik'
import { useEffect } from 'react'

const FormErrorNotification = () => {
    const { isValid, isValidating, isSubmitting } = useFormikContext()

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!isValid && !isValidating && isSubmitting) {
            alert('Fix your form errors!')
        }
    }, [isSubmitting, isValid, isValidating])

    return null
}

export default FormErrorNotification
```

And use it like so:

```
<Formik ...>
    <FormErrorNotification />
    ...
</Formik>
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer for current versions of React and Formik.

Answer (score 1):

there was pretty simple way to do that.

On your submit buttons onClick Method you can define a method like this;

```
<button onClick={() => scrollToErrors(errors)} > //errors param is formik's errors param.
```

https://formik.org/docs/guides/validation#validationschema

```
const scrollToErrors = (errors) => {
    const errorKeys = Object.keys(errors);
    if (errorKeys.length > 0) {
      document.getElementsByName(errorKeys[0])[0].focus();
    }  
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `validate` method to accomplish this. Just make sure you return the error object, so the form can handle the validation.

```
  <Formik
    onSubmit={async values => {
      console.log('submit', values)
    }}
    validate={values => {
      const errors = {}
     
      // Check the values object, and add custom validation 

      return errors
    }}
  ></Formik>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you did not use `<Formik>` component and instead you used a component such as `<Form>` from `reactstrap` library with `useFormik` hook, you can check it out where you call formik's handleSubmit event like that

```
const formik = useFormik({
  initialValues : initialValues,
  onSubmit: (values) => {
  },
  validationSchema: validationSchema
});
```

```
if (formik.isValid)
  formik.handleSubmit()
else alert('Please fill in all fields!')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Worked Well For me

```
<Formik
                    initialValues={params}
                    onSubmit={formHandler}
                    validationSchema={validationSchema}
                    innerRef={checkOutDetails}
                    enableReinitialize
                >
                    {({ submitCount, errors, values, isValidating, isSubmitting, isValid }) => (
                        <>
                            {!isValid &&
                                !isValidating &&
                                isSubmitting &&
                                setTimeout(() => {
                                    toast.error(
                                        'The information is incomplete; please review all red fields and re-submit.'
                                    );
                                }, 300)}
                            <Form>
                               //Your form fields
                            </Form>

                        </>
                     )}
      </Formik>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Formik via `useFormik` hook you have a formik instance object you can access inside your component. This way you can put a `useEffect` to listen to `formik.isValid` change. Serves a callback role very nicely:

```
const formik = useFormik({
  initialValues: {}
})

useEffect(() => {
  onValidationChange(formik.isValid)
}, [formik.isValid, onValidationChange])
```

Answer (score -1):

I guess the above answer can solve your issue, recenlty I have created few forms (some complex ones too), using the `react hook forms` library. This is better than formik and redux forms. I would suggest to try it once, easy to plug and play with lots of dynamic features and validations (including patterns as well). https://react-hook-form.com/